# How can I bind plugin token with my chrome plugin for the application deployed on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-chrome, file-io, plugins

I an developing a plugin in Chrome and the entire application is going to get deployed on Google App Engine. The programming language on the server side is Java.

I need to generate a unique key or token whenever my plugin is downloaded and need to bind the generated key through manifest file of my plugin so that I would be able to detect the request source as to which plugin sent me the request on my sever.

How I should go about to achieve the result?

One of the option is that while downloading I write the generated key to the plugin manifest file. But Google App Engine doesn't allow us to write in a file. So that option cannot be considered.

Managing the operation through Blobstore is an option. But is it the appropriate way to handle the problem or is there any other way to tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create an entity in the datastore, and use the entity id.

You can store plugin info in the entity too.

Comment: But, I think that will not solve my purpose. The reason why I need to bind plugins with key is that whenever a request comes to my server via a plugin, I will first validate the plugin token to check whether the request is from a valid plugin and if yes then only will process further. At the end of the month I need to analyze the count of requests from each of my plugin. So I need to have a unique identification from each of my plugin making the request and datastore is something that resides on server side. How exactly is the transaction going to get managed?

Comment: In the download process, you can generate a key and insert it into the manifest file that is being served to the client.  This would only work if the clients download their extension directly from you, instead of the Chrome app store.  Another way to do this is to call the server to generate a key the first time your extension runs.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The second option is what that I was also thinking and that will work fine. But if I need to go by the first option, the problem that I am facing is that how can I insert the key to the manifest file as for inserting key I need to write in to the manifest file and Google App Engine doesn't allow us to write in a file and the first option seems to be a better one than the second. So if first option needs to be implemented through GAE, how it can be done?

Comment: read the manifest file, modify it, and then serve the modified file to the client via http without writing it anywhere.

Comment: But where to make the modification in the file. I think you are also talking to make modifications at server side but GAE doesn't allow to do that. That is the biggest problem....

Comment: Edit the file in memory.  I'm a little lost on where the difficulty is.  I may have misunderstood your problem.  Please edit your question and describe exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: In order to bind a key with extension, I need to open the manifest file and need to modify that file with the key value generated. Now, all this processing would take place at server side because the downloaded extension will store this value. But the problem is that, my application is deployed on Google App Engine and GAE doesn't allow us to write or even modify a file. So the problem is if the above mentioned process needs to be done at server side, how would I be able to do that with Google App Engine. I hope I am clear as to what my problem is?

Comment: I'm assuming the server reads the file and then serves it to the client via HTTP?  Just modify it in memory before serving it to the client.

Comment: That is what the exact problem is with Google App Engine. It doesn't allow us to write or modify any file in memory. But if there is any way that we can handle this thing with GAE, it will be great !!!

Comment: You certainly can, although I have no idea how you're trying to do it that makes you think you can't.  Fail.  Next time if you want help, please post actual code and details on what exactly is or isn't working so people can help you.